# How get just the "time" part from a datetime.strptime object python

Tags: python, datetime, time, strptime

I have data like this: "2016-10-17 09:34:02" with the format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" and I use: `from datetime import datetime`

My variable is like this:

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(datetemp, format)
```

So far, so good...

But I need get only the time part from this object (date_object) to make some comparisons...

When I do this:

```
print(date_object.time)
```

I get the following error:

```
built-in method time of datetime.datetime object at 0x00A94AE8
```

How can i get just the time part from the object `date_object`? This will allow me to make comparisons within hourly ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis `()` to your `print(date_object.time)` call:

```
print(date_object.time())
```

Example output:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.time()
datetime.time(22, 14, 6, 996000)
>>> print(now.time())
22:14:06.996000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime as dt 
>>> timenow = dt.datetime.now()
>>> timenow
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 23, 9, 59, 54, 291083)
>>> timenow.date()
datetime.date(2016, 11, 23)
>>> timenow.time()
datetime.time(9, 59, 54, 291083)
```

the outputs are in datetime type.

```
>>> print(datetime.time())
00:00:00
```

or you can convert it into a string and print

```
>>> time_str = str(timenow.time())
>>> time_str
'09:59:54.291083'
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_object.time().__str__()` this will give you the format you want

```
date_object.time().__str__() is equal to `print(date_object.time())`
```

but you can store it in a var, not just print it in you screen.